# Simple solution for testing spring boot and angular2 app?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I have built a simple web application that uses Spring Boot for server side operations (with REST endpoints) and Angular2 for the front end. The applications are separate (e.g. not in the same directory structure). if I launch the spring boot app on, say, 8080, and the angular2 on port 4200 and try interacting between the two I get CORS errors. It must be possible run both on the same machine for testing? I am using the build in apache server that comes with spring boot projects, how would I go about creating a header that allows CORS?

I have tried using Docker and heroku as possible ways to get around working on a single machine but no luck.

I have tried the solution suggested, and am still getting the following error:

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/rest/b. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
scheduleTask (main.bundle.js:66162)
scheduleTask (main.bundle.js:65104)
send (Anonymous Script 1 (line 2))
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:40330)
subscribe (main.bundle.js:10885)
subscribe (main.bundle.js:10882)
searchWord (main.bundle.js:66254)
_handle_keyup_13_1 (SearchComponent.ngfactory.js:301)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:54098)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:28471)
onInvoke (main.bundle.js:54664)
runGuarded (main.bundle.js:64998)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65124)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65024)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
[Error] EXCEPTION: More tasks executed then were scheduled.
handleError (main.bundle.js:37937)
next (main.bundle.js:24397:94)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:25913)
__tryOrUnsub (main.bundle.js:44413)
next (main.bundle.js:44362)
_next (main.bundle.js:44315)
next (main.bundle.js:44279)
next (main.bundle.js:19954)
emit (main.bundle.js:25905)
onHandleError (main.bundle.js:54685)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65027)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:66154)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65124)
onInvokeTask (main.bundle.js:54655)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65123)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65024)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
send
scheduleTask (main.bundle.js:66162)
scheduleTask (main.bundle.js:65104)
send (Anonymous Script 1 (line 2))
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:40330)
subscribe (main.bundle.js:10885)
subscribe (main.bundle.js:10882)
searchWord (main.bundle.js:66254)
_handle_keyup_13_1 (SearchComponent.ngfactory.js:301)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:54098)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:28471)
onInvoke (main.bundle.js:54664)
runGuarded (main.bundle.js:64998)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65124)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65024)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
[Error] ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
handleError (main.bundle.js:37942)
next (main.bundle.js:24397:94)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:25913)
__tryOrUnsub (main.bundle.js:44413)
next (main.bundle.js:44362)
_next (main.bundle.js:44315)
next (main.bundle.js:44279)
next (main.bundle.js:19954)
emit (main.bundle.js:25905)
onHandleError (main.bundle.js:54685)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65027)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:66154)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65124)
onInvokeTask (main.bundle.js:54655)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65123)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65024)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
send
scheduleTask (main.bundle.js:66162)
scheduleTask (main.bundle.js:65104)
send (Anonymous Script 1 (line 2))
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:40330)
subscribe (main.bundle.js:10885)
subscribe (main.bundle.js:10882)
searchWord (main.bundle.js:66254)
_handle_keyup_13_1 (SearchComponent.ngfactory.js:301)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:54098)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:28471)
onInvoke (main.bundle.js:54664)
runGuarded (main.bundle.js:64998)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65124)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65024)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
[Error] _updateTaskCount@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65157:32
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65128:42
runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65024:57
invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65192:40
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:66154:32
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65124:42
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:54655:47
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65123:54
runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65024:57
invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65192:40
send@[native code]
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:66162:25
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65104:36
send
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:40330:22
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:10885:37
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:10882:26
searchWord@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:66254:63
_handle_keyup_13_1
[native code]
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:54098:36
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28471:48
onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:54664:43
runGuarded@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64998:53
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65124:42
runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65024:57
invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65192:40
handleError (main.bundle.js:37943)
next (main.bundle.js:24397:94)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:25913)
__tryOrUnsub (main.bundle.js:44413)
next (main.bundle.js:44362)
_next (main.bundle.js:44315)
next (main.bundle.js:44279)
next (main.bundle.js:19954)
emit (main.bundle.js:25905)
onHandleError (main.bundle.js:54685)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65027)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:66154)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65124)
onInvokeTask (main.bundle.js:54655)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65123)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65024)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
send
scheduleTask (main.bundle.js:66162)
scheduleTask (main.bundle.js:65104)
send (Anonymous Script 1 (line 2))
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:40330)
subscribe (main.bundle.js:10885)
subscribe (main.bundle.js:10882)
searchWord (main.bundle.js:66254)
_handle_keyup_13_1 (SearchComponent.ngfactory.js:301)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:54098)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:28471)
onInvoke (main.bundle.js:54664)
runGuarded (main.bundle.js:64998)
invokeTask (main.bundle.js:65124)
runTask (main.bundle.js:65024)
invoke (main.bundle.js:65192)
```

here is the angular code that I am using to access the localhost:8080

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {TreeService} from "../../service/tree.service";

@Component({
selector: 'app-search',
templateUrl: './search.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

searchStr: string;

constructor(private _treeService: TreeService) { }

searchWord() {
this._treeService.searchWord(this.searchStr).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
}
}


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TreeService {

private searchUrl:string;

constructor(private _http:Http) { }

searchWord(str:string){
this.searchUrl = 'localhost:8080/rest/' + str;
return this._http.get(this.searchUrl)
  .map(res => res.json())
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible to run spring-boot enabled app and angular2 on the same machine. As you mentioned they both are running on different ports, a request sent by angular2 is treated as [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) since it has different domain than spring-boot.

You need to add CORS mappings in spring-boot bean configuration something like

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

In above example, it will allow every resource of spring boot from any origin. To restrict the access you can add mapping in following fasion

```
registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
```

Or for specific resource it will be

```
    registry.addMapping("/some-resource-url-of-spring-boot-app")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
```

Comment: just so I understand correctly, suppose I put this in a config directory inside the spring boot project. does it need to be called or auto wired anywhere?

Comment: Not in config directory, simply put this in any class that has been annotated with @Configuration. Spring will pick up this config during component scan. No need to autowire anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

With spring 5+ slight changes

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
        }
    };
}
```